# Developer experience/cost for WindowsCE 6

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

Soon we'll be receiving some WindowsCE6 enabled devices
and I'm wondering what the developer experience is and what the costs are.

I gathered the .NET Compact Framework is supported,
but can you use VS2010 and do we need to buy any additional licenses?

We want to build long running applications with no UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to develop applications for Windows CE 6.0 you can use VS2008 professional for both native (C/C++) and managed (.NET Compact Framework) application development. No support is available for VS2010.
The manufacturer of your device can give you an SDK (mandatory for native apps dev) that will allow you to use only the OS features that are included in the OS image on the device (Windows CE is componentized and usually only a set of components is available on a specific device).
If you need to build your own version of the OS you need to buy Platform Builder that is a VS2005 add-on (its license includes a VS license, IIRC) and a BSP from the device manufacturer. In this case you'll be able to add or remove components to the OS design, adapting it to your own application needs.

Comment: Use VS2005 for .NET CF 2.0 and VS2008 for .NET CF 3.5. Later VS editions are for Windows Mobile 7.0 and higher. Our experience of Windows CE has been positive. We use an ARM 600MHz, dual core processor and provided you're not doing anything hard-core such as processing large images, the performance and features of CE 6.0 are good.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is all included in the Visual Studio package.

I have had some experience developing for the older Windows CE platforms, and these were just included. For the newer platforms, you can download the tools freely at http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started.

Comment: This seems to be for Windows Phone 7 and Xbox360, the entire WindowsCE system seems to be different... only thing I could find was VS2005 support and a 900$ annual subscription requirement

Comment: I posted the link because these packages tend to be compatible with multiple platforms. I don't have the mobile tools installed anymore, so I cannot check for you. If you have them installed, try to create a new "mobile" project and see whether you can set the target to CE 6.